# ReSharper Ultimate Naming Styles Not Being Applied

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, naming-conventions

In ReSharper>Options>Code Editing>C++>Naming Style, I stipulated class fields be prefixed with ‘m_’. I did this for both my personal solution and 'This Computer'.

I tried running ‘Cleanup Code’, ‘Find Code Issues’, and ‘Inspect Current Project for Code Issues’.

Still, the class fields that do not conform to the ‘m_’ convention are not being found.

I understand that ReSharper should find and warn me about nonconforming code. Am I misunderstanding ReSharper or do I need to do something extra in order to enforce the naming convention?

Let me know if I can be more clear.

Comment: Please look at the following link for answer. [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198911/how-to-apply-resharper-ultimate-naming-styles-for-c)