# How to apply ReSharper Ultimate Naming Styles for C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, resharper, naming-conventions

I don't know how to apply naming style for C++ language in Resharper Ultimate Extension for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. My OS is Windows 10. Everything works fine for other languages (like C#) and I have only this problem with C++ language. In ReSharper>Options>Code Editing>C++>Naming Style, I stipulated class names to be all lowercase. I tried running ‘Cleanup Code’, ‘Find Code Issues’, and ‘Inspect Current Project for Code Issues’. Still, the class fields that do not conform to my convention are not being found.

I understand that ReSharper should find and warn me about nonconforming code. Am I misunderstanding ReSharper or do I need to do something extra in order to enforce the naming convention?

Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ReSharper naming style inspections are not yet implemented for C++. Please vote for the corresponding [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-14010) to get an update when it's implemented. At the moment naming style settings are used only to generate new identifiers.